# How to setup STUN settings in PJSIP ios application?

Tags: ios, nat, pjsip, stun

I have voip application based on pjsua. It works fine except that I don't know how to set up STUN settings correct.

Now I connect STUN before pjsua init -

```
cfg.stun_host = pj_str(&stunAdr);
```

after that all works fine if clients not in the same network. But when they in the same network, they don't use NAT and therefore they don't need STUN but STUN is connected and used and clients don't hear each other.

So how to set up using of STUN only when it needed? Depends on NAT present between clients of not?
I'm connecting

```
cfg.cb.on_nat_detect = &on_nat; 

static void on_nat(const pj_stun_nat_detect_result *result) {
    if (result->status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
        pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "NAT detection failed", result->status);


    } else {

        PJ_LOG(3, (THIS_FILE, "NAT detected as %s", result->nat_type_name));

    }
}
```

- its work fine also, detect NAT but how to use it..

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
        // Disable STUN for a new config obtained from the old one, where acc_id is
        // old config id

        // declare a new account config
        pjsua_acc_config acc_cfg_new;

        // create a new pj pool used when copying the existing config
        pj_pool_t *pool = pjsua_pool_create("tmp-pjsua", 1000, 1000);

        // default the new account configuration
        pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg_new);

        // now copy the existing account config - if you already have one
        pjsua_acc_get_config(acc_id, pool, &acc_cfg_new);

        // disable all stun on new account config
        acc_cfg_new.sip_stun_use = PJSUA_STUN_USE_DISABLED;
        acc_cfg_new.media_stun_use = PJSUA_STUN_USE_DISABLED; 


        // Now apply the new config without STUN to the current config
        pjsua_acc_modify(acc_id, &acc_cfg_new);

        // and make a call
```

Comment: Please expand your answer with some description and explanation. Calling out your in-code comments will improve the readability.

Comment: This piece of code will set up an acc_cfg without STUN. It can be used when the case requiring no STUN is required in the code.

        // disable all stun on new account config
        acc_cfg_new.sip_stun_use = PJSUA_STUN_USE_DISABLED;
        acc_cfg_new.media_stun_use = PJSUA_STUN_USE_DISABLED;

The above is the key piece of code.